# How to reshape long to wide data in Stata?

Tags: stata, data-management

I have the following data:

```
id      tests      testvalue
1       A           4
1       B           5
1       C           3
1       D           3 
2       A           3
2       B           3
3       C           3
3       D           4
4       A           3
4       B           5
4       A           1
4       B           3
```

I would like to change the above long data format into following wide data.

```
id      testA   testB    testC   testD   index
1       4      5        3         3        1
2       3      3        .         .        2
3       .      .        3         4        3
4       3      5        .         .        4
4       1      3        .         .        5
```

I am trying

```
reshape wide testvalue, i(id) j(tests)
```

It gives error because there are no unique values within `tests`.

What would be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an extra identifier to make replicates distinguishable.

```
clear 
input id  str1    tests      testvalue
1       A           4
1       B           5
1       C           3
1       D           3 
2       A           3
2       B           3
3       C           3
3       D           4
4       A           3
4       B           5
4       A           1
4       B           3
end 
bysort id tests: gen replicate = _n 
reshape wide testvalue, i(id replicate) j(tests) string
```

See also [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/) for documentation.