# How to get the union of two date vectors in Stata?

Tags: stata, reshape

I have the following data:

```
id  test1   test1_date    test2 test2_date
1   2   Jun 23, 2014 21:29  26  Jun 20, 2014 06:27
1   2   Jun 24, 2014 01:44  25  Jun 21, 2014 02:53 
1   2   Jun 24, 2014 06:20  25  Jun 22, 2014 07:38
2   2   Jun 25, 2014 22:15  30  Jun 26, 2014 11:08
2   0   Jun 26, 2014 02:35  25  Jun 27, 2014 20:09
2   2   Jun 26, 2014 06:49  25  Jun 30, 2014 14:47
```

This is in so-called wide format. I would like to convert it to long format as follows:

```
id  date               test value
1   Jun 20, 2014 06:27  2   26
1   Jun 21, 2014 02:53  2   25
1   Jun 22, 2014 07:38  2   25
1   Jun 23, 2014 21:29  1   2
1   Jun 24, 2014 01:44  1   2
1   Jun 24, 2014 06:20  1   2
2   Jun 25, 2014 22:15  1   2
2   Jun 26, 2014 02:35  1   0
2   Jun 26, 2014 06:49  1   2
2   Jun 26, 2014 11:08  2   30
2   Jun 27, 2014 20:09  2   25
2   Jun 30, 2014 14:47  2   25
```

I tried the `reshape` command:

```
reshape test1 test2, i(id)
```

However, it creates a missing values vector.
Another try was

```
reshape long test1 test2 , i(id test1_date test2_date)
```

Comment: After attempting to use reshape and failing, I believe that creating two datasets and using append would be the simplest approach for this straightforward task. If there were many date/time pairs I might feel otherwise.

Comment: Date times shown with date-time display formats are very awkward for members to experiment with. Your dataset should be shown in a form that allows easy import.

Comment: Mata has vectors. Here by vector you presumably mean variable.

Comment: What is the relation of this to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536315/how-to-transform-long-to-wide-data-in-stata  or to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839986/how-to-reshape-long-to-wide-data-in-stata ? You seem to be asking the same questions again and again. Please be explicit about links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's personal taste, but I advise against the term "format" here. It's already overloaded (display format, file format). I suggest simply "shape".

The problem is soluble, but you need two small tricks and to reverse one misunderstanding:

1. Stata wants another identifier variable because its underlying idea is that the `reshape` should be reversible. So, that needs to be created even if it is arbitrary.
2. The variable names would benefit from some work.
3. The date variables don't serve to identify groups of observations, as their values are distinct, not repeated.

There is generic advice (beyond the help and manual entry) in [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/).

Some of this syntax is just needed to set up your example as reproducible code. A good question would do that for us!

```
. clear

. input id  test1 str18  Stest1_date    test2 str18 Stest2_date

            id      test1         Stest1_date      test2         Stest2_date
  1. 1   2   "Jun 23, 2014 21:29"  26  "Jun 20, 2014 06:27"
  2. 1   2   "Jun 24, 2014 01:44"  25  "Jun 21, 2014 02:53" 
  3. 1   2   "Jun 24, 2014 06:20"  25  "Jun 22, 2014 07:38"
  4. 2   2   "Jun 25, 2014 22:15"  30  "Jun 26, 2014 11:08"
  5. 2   0   "Jun 26, 2014 02:35"  25  "Jun 27, 2014 20:09"
  6. 2   2   "Jun 26, 2014 06:49"  25  "Jun 30, 2014 14:47"
  7. end 

. 
. gen double test1_date = clock(Stest1_date, "MDY hm")

. gen double test2_date = clock(Stest2_date, "MDY hm")

. drop S*

. format t*date %tc

. l, sepby(id)

     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   test1   test2           test1_date           test2_date |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1       2      26   23jun2014 21:29:00   20jun2014 06:27:00 |
  2. |  1       2      25   24jun2014 01:44:00   21jun2014 02:53:00 |
  3. |  1       2      25   24jun2014 06:20:00   22jun2014 07:38:00 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |  2       2      30   25jun2014 22:15:00   26jun2014 11:08:00 |
  5. |  2       0      25   26jun2014 02:35:00   27jun2014 20:09:00 |
  6. |  2       2      25   26jun2014 06:49:00   30jun2014 14:47:00 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------+

. 
. bysort id : gen j = _n

. rename (test1_date test2_date) (date1 date2)

. reshape long test date, i(id j)
(note: j = 1 2)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        6   ->      12
Number of variables                   6   ->       5
j variable (2 values)                     ->   _j
xij variables:
                            test1 test2   ->   test
                            date1 date2   ->   date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. l, sepby(id)

     +-----------------------------------------+
     | id   j   _j   test                 date |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   1    1      2   23jun2014 21:29:00 |
  2. |  1   1    2     26   20jun2014 06:27:00 |
  3. |  1   2    1      2   24jun2014 01:44:00 |
  4. |  1   2    2     25   21jun2014 02:53:00 |
  5. |  1   3    1      2   24jun2014 06:20:00 |
  6. |  1   3    2     25   22jun2014 07:38:00 |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  7. |  2   1    1      2   25jun2014 22:15:00 |
  8. |  2   1    2     30   26jun2014 11:08:00 |
  9. |  2   2    1      0   26jun2014 02:35:00 |
 10. |  2   2    2     25   27jun2014 20:09:00 |
 11. |  2   3    1      2   26jun2014 06:49:00 |
 12. |  2   3    2     25   30jun2014 14:47:00 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: For readers starting out with `reshape`, notice that the _stubnames_ can also take more "complicated" forms. In this example we could go directly with `reshape long test test@_date, i(id j)`, and not do the `rename`.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Quite correct, and I've tweaked the answer accordingly. To me that syntax (although perfectly rational) is too arbitrary for me to look up each time or to remember, so in practice I always prefer to tweak the variable names directly for which the syntax is memorable. But you are right in implying that to be personal preference, not an absolute necessity.

Comment: I initially thought of it as something really mysterious. Then I started viewing it as a placeholder for `j`. It has kind of stuck since then.

Comment: Good tip. We all avoid syntax we dislike when there's a choice, I imagine.